# How do I create a key-value PHP array/JS object from two blocks of lines in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2

So I've got two separate blocks (on the same document), one with keys:

```
one
two
three
```

Another one with values:

```
First
Second
Third
```

And I want to join them into a PHP array:

```
$arr = [
    'one' => 'First',
    'two' => 'Second',
    'three' => 'Third',
],
```

Or a Javascript/JSON object (So I make this question more googlers-friendly :D):

```
var obj = {
    one: 'First',
    two: 'Second',
    three: 'Third'
};
```

Ideas using cool Sublime Text shortcuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I figured out after placing the question so here it goes.

For PHP arrays:

1. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all.
2. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to place a cursor at the end of each line.
3. <kbd>'</kbd> to wrap each line on single quotes.
4. Select all the "value" lines.
5. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to place a cursor at the end of each line.
6. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut all value lines. (NOTE: cutting them as multiple cursor selection cuts them as 'separate chunks').
7. Select all the "key" lines.
8. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to place a cursor at the end of each line.
9. <kbd>Right</kbd> to remove individual selections.
10. Type `=>` to add the PHP array arrows.
11. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste.
12. Type `,` to add the end of the line comma.
13. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all.
14. Hit <kbd>[</kbd> to wrap the whole selection in brackets.

For Javascript/JSON:

1. Select all the "value" lines.
2. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to place a cursor at the end of each line.
3. <kbd>'</kbd> to wrap each line on single quotes.
4. Select all the "value" lines again.
5. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to place a cursor at the end of each line.
6. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut all value lines. (NOTE: cutting them as multiple cursor selection cuts them as 'separate chunks').
7. Select all the "key" lines.
8. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to place a cursor at the end of each line.
9. <kbd>Right</kbd> to remove individual selections.
10. Type `:` to add the PHP array arrows.
11. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste.
12. Type `,` to add the end of the line comma.
13. Remove the last line comma.
14. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all.
15. Hit <kbd>[</kbd> to wrap the whole selection in brackets.

PC users, feel welcomed to to add PC shortcuts!